# Having trouble managing multiple sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm having trouble figuring out the logic behind having multiple sockets connected to the same server trying to communicate with one another. I'll try and describe my situation with some psudeo code

```
clientsocket1 connects
clientsocket2 connects

Client one sends an emit
clientsocket1.emits('ConversionDone')

Node handles the emit
serverSocket.on(ConversionDone, function(data){
//Store Convert files into an array
serverSocket.emit('Files')//this is intended to notify clientsocket2
}
```

how in the following situation would I be able to notify clientsocket2 that ConversionDone has finished  if clientsocket1 was the socket that initated the emit?

Comment: well your pseudo code looks good? Server listens and re-emits... What is your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255969/socket-io-client-to-client-messaging

Comment: thanks for the reference this was what I was looking for