# python-socketio client to client messaging

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, client, python-socketio

Can I send messages from one client directly to another using `python-socketio`?

It can be done using `socketio` as follows:

```js
socket.join('room')
```

```js
io.sockets.in('room').emit('event_name', data)
```

> Source: [socket.io client to client messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255969/socket-io-client-to-client-messaging)

I can't find any documentation on how this works with `python-socketio`. Could someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The following in `socketio`

```
io.sockets.in('room').emit('event_name', data)
```

is the same as this in `python-socketio`:

```
io.emit("HelloWorld", some_dict, room="room")
```

Here is the link to the official doc -> [link](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#rooms)

Answer (score 0):

The Socket.IO protocol allows bidirectional client-to-server communication, but clients are not connected among themselves so they cannot communicate directly. To implement client-to-client you have to pass through the server and it works as follows:

- Client A emits an event to the server, indicating who is Client B, the recipient of the message, and what data it wishes to send to that client.
- In the server, the handler for the event from Client A, emits an event addressed to Client B with the data passed by Client A in the first event.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was under the impression this was possible from the mentioned post. I have implemented something similar to what you described.